# How to display a calendar on click of a textbox with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box and a submit button. On clicking on text box,calender is showing.
my problem is that the following code has css or js file which has url of Http etc.I want css or js file on my system from following link because i am working on IBM RAD and can't use external files.
So,please help me.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
                    minDate: "-6M ", 
                    maxDate: -60 
                }); 
            });  
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you copy the files and save them locally?

Comment: @Oriol his problem is he can't use externally hosted scripts, so how is changing to another external host going to work?

Comment: I tried this but its not working properly.
Calender is there bt look and feel is not as required.
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing jQuery and jQuery UI from CDN.

Instead, you can download [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and use these files from your local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the links, 
1.open the link in the crome browser, 
2.just say CTRL+S, (save as) then click on save button to your working directory, 
3.Change your links accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Right click on your web page and go to "view page source".Then you will get a screen shown in image. And you can download all files by clicking on them.Copy and add them in you project.[image]

Comment: I tried this but its not working properly.
Calender is there bt look and feel is not as required.